# retain previous position of floating action button android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to retain the position of floating action button when the app is closed and show FAB again at the previous position when the app is opened again.

Comment: Pls share your code

Answer (score 0):

store the previous position of floating action button before moving like this

```
LayoutParams positionOfButton = floatingActionButton.getLayoutParams();
```

and again when it is needed to restore button to its original position do this,

```
floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(positionOfButton);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using the sharedPreferences concept. You have to capture the coordinates of FAB and store them in preferences.

```
 SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("values",0);
 int[] i=new int[2];
  FAB.getLocationOnScreen(i); 
  sp.edit().putString(i[0]+"").commit();
  sp.edit().putString(i[1]+"").commit();
  //while retrieving parse to double. and then set 
   FAB.setX(x);
   FAB.setY(y); //where x and y are double values from sharedpreferences.
```